# How using rollback if there is mysql and restfull API transaction in node js

Tags: mysql, node.js, rollback

I have some transaction in node js, the first is select data from mysql table (table : customers), and the second is insert data into mysql table (table : customers), the third is send data and save using restfull API and the last is insert data into mysql table (table : generate_spks), I want to apply rollback in my node js.

I have tried like this, but if the last transaction failed (which is insert into generate_spks table), the data that I send and save using the restfull API is kept (still running), even though it should not be sent because the last transaction failed.

I have tried like this link https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#transactions

this is my `db.js`

```
var mysql = require("mysql");

function Connection() {

    this.pool = null;

    var konek = {
        host: '19*.16*.**.***',
        user: 'my_user',
        password: 'my_password',
        database: 'my_database'
    };

    this.init = function() {
        this.pool = mysql.createPool(konek);
    }

    this.acquire = function(callback) {
        this.init();
        this.pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
            callback(err, connection);
        });
    };
}
module.exports = new Connection();
```

and this is my `controller`

```
var connection = require('../../config/db');

function Todo() {

this.insertSpkBranchNo = function(req, res, next) {
    var id = uuidv1();
    var cust_code = 'C-0001'
    var cust_nama = req.body.cust_nama;
    var cust_noktp = req.body.cust_noktp;
    var cust_kk = req.body.cust_kk;
    var created = new Date();
    var modified = new Date();

    connection.acquire(function(err, con) {
      con.beginTransaction(function(){
        con.query('SELECT cust_code FROM customers ORDER BY cust_code desc LIMIT 1', function(err, result){
           if (err) {
              con.rollback(function(){
              console.log(err);
              res.send({ status: 400, message: 'Select Customer Code Failed' });
              });
           } 

           con.query('INSERT INTO customers (id,cust_code,cust_nama,cust_noktp,cust_kk,created,modified) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', [id,cust_code,cust_nama,cust_noktp,cust_kitas,created,modified], function(err, result) {
               if (err) {
                  con.rollback(function(){
                  console.log(err);
                  return res.send({ status: 400, message: 'Insert Customer Failed' });
                  });
               } 

               var url = 'http://45.**.***.***/api-dev/api_insert_customer.php';

               var requestData = {
                   id:id,
                   cust_code:cust_code,
                   cust_nama:cust_nama,
                   cust_noktp:cust_noktp,
                   created:created, 
                   modified:modified,
                   cust_kk:cust_kk,
                }

                var data = {
                   url: url,
                   auth: {
                   bearer: '71D55F99*****'
                   },
                json: true,
                form: requestData,
                rejectUnauthorized: false, //add when working with https sites
                requestCert: false, //add when working with https sites
                agent: false, //add when working with https sites
               }

               request.post(data, function(err, httpResponse, body) {
                  if (body.status == "0") {
                     con.rollback(function(){
                     console.log(err);
                     return res.send({ status: 400, message: 'Send customer to dms Failed' });
                     });
                   }  

                   var id = uuidv1();
                   var id_customer = req.body.id_customer;
                   var cust_nama = req.body.cust_nama;
                   var cust_alamat = req.body.cust_alamat;
                   var cust_hp = req.body.cust_hp;
                   var cust_telp = req.body.cust_telp;
                   var cust_npwp = req.body.cust_npwp;

                   con.query('INSERT INTO generate_spks (id, id_customer, cust_nama, cust_alamat, cust_hp, cust_telp, cust_npwp) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', [id, id_customer, cust_nama, cust_alamat, cust_hp, cust_telp, cust_npwp], function(err, result) {
                      if (err) {
                         con.rollback(function(){
                         console.log(err);
                         return res.json({ status: 400, message: 'Insert spk failed' });
                         });
                       }

                       con.commit(function(err) {
                          if (err) { 
                            con.rollback(function() {
                            console.log(err);
                            return res.json({ status: 400, message: 'Commit failed' });
                            });
                           } else {
                             return res.json({ status: 200, message: 'success' });
                           }
                      });

                   });

                 });

              });

            });   

          });

          console.log('Transaction Complete.');
          con.end();
        });
    };
}

module.exports = new Todo();
```

I want if the last transaction (insert into generate_spks table) is failed, the third transaction (using restfull API) will not be saved.

Is my code wrong? any help is appreciate. Thank you..

Comment: Since the third transaction is implemented in API it is not part of the current transaction, so you will have to delete it manually by implementing a query to revert changes made in the third transaction.

Comment: @DarkShadow so I can't apply rollback to my transaction?

Comment: Yes since that particular query in API is running on different connections as per my guess. Why have you implemented that operation in API separately, is it hosted on a different server?

Comment: @DarkShadow Yes, it is in different server

Comment: @DarkShadow is there no other way to implement rollback with this API?

Comment: You will have to implement separate Failure API to rollback the API transaction in case of failure and call this Failure API on other transactions rollback